# How to control AMD GPU fan speed

Tags: 20.04, amd-graphics, ubuntu-mate, fancontrol

There may be some similar threads, but they are rather old.

I've recently been having a nightmare with Nvidia and Ubuntu with my specific motherboard. I ended up going for a new motherboard and AMD GPU instead.

My old GPU was the EVGA GTX1650. After asking around, there was some pretty good software called GreenWithEnvy that allowed me to set extremely specific profiles for fan speed and GPU temperature. I don't want to mess around trying to overclock memory - my main priority is to try and get the fans to be quieter.

My new card is the AMD MSI RX6500XT. The cooling is actually pretty impressive compared to my old card. However, the default profile is too loud for me to tolerate.

In windows, there is AMD radion software that more or less lets me do what i want, although doesn't allow you to be as specific as GreenWithEnvy did.

From the tests that I did with the software on windows, this cards GPU temperature stays well under 70 degrees even when gaming and I had set the fan speed to 34% (and interestingly 30% is the lowest they can go). 50% and over sounds ridiculous to me. My whole aluminium case starts resonating like an engine when they run this high unless i stand it on foam. I would rather they stayed at the same RPM when gaming until it gets closer to running a little to hot. For me, low noise is more important than overclocking to get the best visual performance.

From what I can tell, there isn't much in the way of programs for Open source cards and overclocking them, and I don't have much understanding of doing things by the command line.

I will mainly be gaming in windows, but I would like the ability to set more or less the same profile for the GPU fans in Linux too as the default is just too loud.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Seems like you need to be able to create a custom fan curve. Try Corectrl, rather simple and has gui.

[just image from internet but corectrl gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIU77.png)

1. Add PPA

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ernstp/mesarc
   ```
2. Update

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Install Corectrl

   ```
   sudo apt install -y corectrl
   ```

**If you want to remove the package and the repository**

```
sudo apt remove corectrl

sudo add-apt-repository —-remove ppa:ernstp/mesarc
```

I can also recommend Radeon Profile, but I don’t think it has custom fan curve.

[this is radeon profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4USl.png)

1. Add PPA

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:radeon-profile/stable
   ```
2. Update

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Install

   ```
   sudo apt install -y radeon-profile
   ```

**If you want to remove package and repository**

```
sudo apt remove radeon-profile

sudo add-apt-repository —-remove ppa:radeon-profile/stable
```

**edit:**
You can get gnome tweaks which is an extended settings package essentailly. In it you will be able to set programs to launch at startup easily.

And yeah you should also be able to set the fan curve to exactly the same as in windows if you want. I don't know if you can copy directly with a file or anything but just try to set the same fan curve and it will be fine.

Comment: Many thanks for this. I will see if i can find a way to get this program to launch after login each time. In the AMD software in windows, the fan curve is set by the junction temperature, which really confused me. I'm guessing this  program you have mentioned is the sensor at the edge for the fan curve temperature. I could just do with working out the temperatures that are safe to get up to. With my fan curve in windows that I'm trying to match here gets up to around 90 occasionally at the junction and close to 70 with the GPU temperature.

Comment: both of these wont work for my and 4600h  GTX 1650 laptop hp pavilion, why though?

Comment: Works fine with my 290X. OP asked for AMD devices, maybe the solution is not compatible to Nvidia.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, now i can add this in my to

~/.bashrc

alias gpu="radeon-profile"

and now just type gpu, for this to pop up.
This is the best sensor yet.